# How do I use the result of idata.frame()?

Tags: r, dataframe, immutability, plyr

I'd like to use the much-praised `idata.frame()` function to speed up some large plyr functions, but it's not returning an immutable data frame in the form that I'm expecting.

All the examples I've seen suggest that I can just assign `idata.frame(baseball)` to a new variable and start working with it, but I'm getting unexpected results from the function:

```
> ibb <- idata.frame(baseball)
> str(ibb)
Classes 'idf', 'environment' <environment: 0x0d0f15d8> 
> ibb
<environment: 0x0d0f15d8>
attr(,"class")
[1] "idf"         "environment"
```

Thanks for any tips. I'm using R version 2.14.1 with plyr 1.7.1.

EDIT: in the example above, it's possible to run `ddply(idata.frame(ibb), .(year), "nrow")` successfully, so the immutable object is working as expected in that regard. I'm wondering why certain `data.frame` behavior isn't available, and if there's any documentation as to the difference.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you've tried to do with `ibb` that hasn't worked? The plyr functions (ddply, dlply, etc) should all work just fine I think.

Comment: I don't know but have you tried `data.table` package?  I'd be interested in any comparisons between `idate.frame` and `data.table`.

Comment: @joran, I thought I could do anything that works on a data frame, like `head()`, which returns 

    <environment: 0x158b42d8>
    attr(,"class")
    [1] "idf"         "environment"

Comment: @joran If you add that comment as the answer, I'll accept it and keep this from becoming bounty-eligible if it doesn't need to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't expect much beyond the **plyr** functions that Hadley wrote to handle `idata.frame` to work. I don't think Hadley wrote methods for anything beyond his own **plyr** functions, and even then his own documentation states that it is experimental.

If you want a more complete integration with `data.frame`, Matthew Dowle is right, use **data.table**.